# Move with php one row to another in database tables

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using php to make some mods on my database, i have two identical tables and i want to move one row from the first table to the second one how can i do that using pure php and mysql.

that is how my tables looks like

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 username varchar(30) primary key,
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

and here is my php code so far

```
function procMoveUser(){
          global $session, $database, $form;
          /* Username error checking */
          $subuser = $this->checkUsername("user");

          /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
          if($form->num_errors > 0){
             $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
             $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
             header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
          }
          /* move the user */
         else{

      $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$subuser'"; 
      $result = $database->query($q); 

      if($result && $result->num_rows == 1){
          while($array = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
              $second_query = "INSERT INTO".TBL_USERSDONT."VALUES ($array['user'], $array['password'], $array['userid'] , $array['userlevel'] , $array['email'] , $array['timestamp'])"; 
              $second_result = $mysqli->query($second_query);
              if($second_result){
                  // it worked!
                  $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$subuser'";
                  $database->query($q);
              }
        }
      }




  }
       }
```

Comment: Why do you need PHP for this at all? `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT FROM table2 ...`.

Comment: .. followed by a DELETE of course, but yeah, pure SQL

Comment: well it's for a web service so the first table was allready there full with items so i want to move them on my new one with php taking them row by row with all the items of every row

Answer (score 1):

First, `SELECT * FROM` the first table for the row that you want to move.  Then, as suggested above, run an INSERT statement with the values from the first table.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($q); 

if($result && $result->num_rows == 1){
    while($array = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        $second_query = "INSERT INTO second_table VALUES ($array['user'], $array['something'])"; 
        $second_result = $mysqli->query($second_query);
        if($second_result){
        // it worked!
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: ok thats good how can i get every value. i 'll use something like $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'"; how can i insert the whole row now to a new array for every value and taking care of the password too wich is md5

Comment: 1)usual warnings about SQL injection  2)fetch_assoc() makes an associative array from the results, with each header of the table as the appropriate index (key); then, 'user' and 'something' would be columns in your tables.

Comment: ok that's good and what about the password? it's stored in md5 format?

Comment: then plop it over into the other table, as is

Comment: 1)need spaces in second_query  2)change $mysqli to $database in second query

Comment: i think there is e problem with quotes or sth

Comment: perhaps single quotes around the values being inserted in the second query (e.g. $array['user']) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [Copy an existing MySQL table to a new table](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/)